# Interpretation of a non-linear optimization problem.

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

> Three points are located in the plane whose coordinates are : (1, 2) , (−2, −1)
> and (1, −1). It is desired to place a fourth point in such a way that the largest of the three
> distances from the fourth point to each of the three given points is the smallest
> possible.

I have some problems with the interpretation here. the points doesnt matter because we want the more generality case. I first thought of assuming that one of the points was the largest, say: $d_1,d_2,d_3$ are the distances and $d_1 > d_2 \ and  \ d_1 >d_3$ so $d_1$ is the largest. But here I am restricting the conditions to $d_1$

Then i thought in the sum of the distances such that: $$min \ d_1 + d_2 + d_3$$
so we have a optimization problem without constrained, but i dont think this is the correct interpretation. i was thinking in a problem with constrained and resolve this with KKT conditions.

Any help is apreciated, thanks.

Comment: Any 3 points make a triangle. My guess is that the fourth point is the Fermat point of the triangle. Also, I think you should consider the relationship between d1, d2, and d3

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify the problem a lot by introducing one extra decision variable to represent the actual target value, call it $M$. Then the problem takes on all of the constraints of the original, and you just add the target $\min M$ along with the set of constraints:

$\forall i (M \geq d_i)$

It's pretty easy to show that in a valid solution $M$ will have to be equal to the largest value out of the $d_i$ - if it's smaller, then it doesn't satisfy the above constraint, but if it's larger, then it's not at its own minimum value and therefore the system is not yet optimal.